# Changing drop down values basing on the value obtained from session storage

Tags: angular

I am writing an application for my project, There is a user invitation form which consists of three fields , user name, email and role(which is a drop down value) My application is this way if user A logs in display 1,2,3,4,5 in the drop down for roles, but if user B logs in display only 3 4 and 5. How to achieve this programatically? I am getting the values of user A ,User B from the session storage, here is the current logic in HTML

```
<option [value]="role.id" *ngFor="let role of roles">{{role.roleName}}</option>
```

Comment: <option [value]="role.id" *ngFor="let role of roles">{{role.roleName}}</option>

Answer (score 0):

```
Service will return the role id, each user is assigned a unique role id, first capture the role id and then do the data handling

      this.inviteService.getRoles().subscribe(data => {
        this.sessionService.set('roles',data);
        this.roles =this.sessionService.get<any>('roles');
        var rolesList: any=[];`enter code here`
        if(this.sessionService.getHigherRoleId() == 2)
//getHigherRoledId is returned from a service, which gives the roleId
        {
          this.roles.forEach(singleRole => {
            if (!((singleRole.id ==1)||(singleRole.id == 3))){
              rolesList.push(singleRole);

            }
          });

          this.roles=[];
         this.roles = rolesList;
        }
```